# Able to delete file without permission

Tags: permissions, rm, chmod, chown

I've been experimenting with file permissions and ownership lately, and I tried this:

```
touch a
sudo chown root:root a
sudo chmod 000 a
```

I can't read, write, or execute the file, but I can still delete it using `-f`. Why is this? I don't own the file, and nobody has any permission for the file. Shouldn't you need root to delete a 000 file you don't own?

```
---------- 1 root  root      0 Apr  3 20:18 a
```

Answer (score 2):

What you call "delete a file" is really just deleting a reference to the file in a directory , and the right to do so is the right to modify the directory; the file permissions play no part in this. If that was the last reference to the file, the file is destroyed, but that is a separate issue.

Comment: What do file permissions change, then? Does this mean you couldn't `srm` it?